# Angular - Iterate over stringified data in the HTML

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have the following data (from an API) - This is just part of the data -, so what I want to do is to iterate over this data in the HTML file in Angular to show them in a Mat Select component, but as you can see the data is stringified, so what could I do about it?

```
  "SurveyPeriods":"[{\"ID\":23524,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-03-20T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-03-26T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23525,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-03-27T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-04-02T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23526,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-04-03T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-04-09T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23527,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-04-10T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-04-16T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23528,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-04-17T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-04-23T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23529,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-04-24T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-04-30T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23530,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-05-01T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-05-07T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23531,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-05-08T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-05-14T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23532,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-05-15T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-05-21T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23533,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-05-22T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-05-28T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23534,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-05-29T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-06-04T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23535,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-06-05T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-06-11T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23536,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-06-12T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-06-18T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23537,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-06-19T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-06-25T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23538,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-06-26T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-07-02T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23539,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-07-03T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-07-09T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23540,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-07-10T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-07-16T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23541,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-07-17T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-07-23T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23542,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-07-24T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-07-30T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23543,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-07-31T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-08-06T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23544,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-08-07T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-08-13T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23545,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-08-14T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-08-20T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23546,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-08-21T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-08-27T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23547,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-08-28T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-09-03T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23548,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-09-04T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-09-10T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23549,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-09-11T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-09-17T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23550,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-09-18T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-09-24T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23551,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-09-25T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-10-01T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23552,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-10-02T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-10-08T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23553,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-10-09T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-10-15T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23554,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-10-16T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-10-22T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23555,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-10-23T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-10-29T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23556,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-10-30T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-11-05T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23557,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-11-06T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-11-12T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23558,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-11-13T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-11-19T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23559,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-11-20T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-11-26T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23560,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-11-27T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-12-03T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23561,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-12-04T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-12-10T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23562,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-12-11T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-12-17T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23563,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-12-18T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-12-24T00:00:00\"},{\"ID\":23564,\"START_DATE\":\"2021-12-25T00:00:00\",\"END_DATE\":\"2021-12-28T00:00:00\"}]"},
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JSON.parse with the value of your `SurveyPeriods` to get an array of javascript elements:

```
JSON.parse("[{\"ID\":23524,\"START.............DATE\":\"2021-12-28T00:00:00\"}]");
```

Comment: You mean to store this in a new array then send it to the HTML??? 
because I need to iterate over it using ngFor

Comment: Or create a method that returns the array out of the attribute on the fly.
It depends on the whole component/logic.